# Finding possible values of entries of a simplex tabeau

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

While solving a standard form problem, we arrive at the following tableau, with $x_3, x_4, and x_5$ being the basic variables:

[image]

The entries α, β, γ, δ, η are unknown parameters. We have to determine
all possible values of α, β, γ, δ, η  such that the current solution is optimal and there are multiple optimal solutions.

The answer key says that the solution is β = 0, δ = 0, γ ≤ 0, η, α unrestricted. I see that β has to be zero because the basic solution is degenerate. But, I don't see how the other conditions are determined. I am guessing this are required to get multiple optimal solutions. Amy help will be appreciated.